# Splitting line at all vertices in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting, pipe-network

I need look through 3025 lines and split them at every vertex, then make points at the end of them and call them fittings. My coworkers would select 1 by 1 and hot key them.

Is there a better way?

These line are steel pipe and the point will be fittings that bends the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these tools depending if you want to actually split the line, or just create points from those vertices:

- [Feature Vertices to Points](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm)
- [Split Line at Vertices](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm)